# Infimum of the Dirichlet energy and deformation of metrics

Tags: riemannian-geometry, regularity

Consider the Dirichlet energy $E(\phi; g,h)=\frac{1}{2}\int_M|d\phi|^2$ of a map $\phi:(M,g)\to(N,h)$ between  Riemannian manifolds, where we assume $M$ and $N$ are compact. Given a path $g(t)$ of Riemannian metrics on $M$, consider the function  \begin{equation}t \mapsto\inf_{\phi}E(\phi; g(t),h),\end{equation} where the infimum is taken over a fixed homotopy class of maps $M\to N$. I was wondering whether there is any regularity result for this function, or if there is any good reference on this topic?